# View unknown IPsec pre-shared key

Tags: cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

I've inherited a Cisco ASA 5510. It was configured by the company that installed it but I don't have any documentation on it.

IPsec VPN is enabled and a pre-shared IKE key is inputted but we do not know what this key is. Is there a way to retrieve the key or can I only reset it?

I would look at a client configuration for the key, but all our clients are configured AnyConnect SSL VPN.

Comment: Does `show run` obfuscate the IKE key?

Comment: Comes out as: `pre-shared-key *****`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `more system:running-config` should show you all of your keys in plain text.

Comment: `pre-shared-key *****`

Comment: try `more system:running-config`

Comment: Yep, `more system:running-config` showed the command in plain text. Thank you!

Comment: If that worked for you please select @resmon6 as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

@resmon6 answer is excellent, but for the sake of completeness - if you save the config to a tftp server using `copy running-config tftp` passwords etc. are not obfuscated.